# WSO2 Single Sign On session timeout

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have connected `Liferay 6.2` and `WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0` with OpenId.
I have 2 iframe portlets in Liferay for Wso2 publisher and store and I use SAML for SSO.
I have set an infinite session timeout in Liferay.
How I can do the same thing in WSO2 Publisher and Store?
I have tried to set SSOService/SessionTimeout tag to 0 and -1 in WSO2-IS/repository/conf/identity.xml but not working.

```
<SSOService>...<SessionTimeout>0</SessionTimeout>...</SSOService>
```

Can you help me?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have to add the time out in WSO2 Identity Server, not in publisher or store

Answer (score 0):

As you are using WSO2IS 5.0.0,you can configure it by editing the value of the following property in /repository/conf/tomcat/carbon/WEB-INF/web.xml file.

`<session-config>
     <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
</session-config>`

Thanks.